# Add multiple ImageView items to an Qt.Window to get several images within one window in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

how can I display multiple images within one QWidget?

So far, I display one image as follows:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Plotwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, title, *args):
        super().__init__(*args) 
        self.plotwindow=QWidget(self,Qt.Window)
        self.image=pg.ImageView(self.plotwindow)
        self.plotwindow.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.plotwindow.show()

img1 = cv2.imread("img_0_VIS.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
window1 = Plotwindow("window1")
window1.image.setImage(img1)
```

Or, if this isn't possible, is there a way to define the position of the window? Such that if I use multiple windows - that they won't be all on top of each other?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not add widgets to `QMainWindow` as direct children.  Instead you should use [`QMainWindow::setCentralWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) and make use of [layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: thanks, this helped me a lot! See answer below ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else wonders this, here a solution that I came up with thanks to G.M.'s comment - showing 4 pyqtgraph ImageView widgets :-)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui  import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import cv2

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # heritate QMainWindow stuff
        self.form_widget = FormWidget( "Camera Streams")  # create widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget) # set as central widget


class FormWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title):        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        self.image=pg.ImageView(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image, 0,0)
        self.image2=pg.ImageView(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image2, 0,1)
        self.image3=pg.ImageView(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image3, 1,0)
        self.image4=pg.ImageView(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image4, 1,1)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)  


path = "your_path"
img1 = cv2.imread(path +"\\img_0_VIS.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img2 = cv2.imread(path +"\\img_1_VIS.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img3 = cv2.imread(path +"\\img_2_VIS.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img4 = cv2.imread(path +"\\img_3_VIS.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

foo = MyMainWindow()
foo.form_widget.image.setImage(img1)
foo.form_widget.image2.setImage(img2)
foo.show()
```